# web page show GPIO pin status (on or off) automatically

Tags: python, web-server

How do I read a raspberry pi GPIO pin value and say show a red or green button on a web page reflecting the pin's current status, and have this automatically update when the GPIO pin's state changes?

Comment: This isnt a place to ask the community to just write all the code for you. Its a space to ask specific questions about an issue you are having. To help you along though, you need to think of this as a multi part process, work on each by itself, and then incorporate them.    So one part is to read all GPIO status ( you can google, there are lots of options)  Then another part is how to build the webpage, (use dummy values for you states) again there are lots of tutorials on this ( you could use AJAX to reload the page on changes). Then once you have both working, you will be able to combine.

Comment: Or at least start off with only getting the GPIO states, and just print them to the console. Then once you have that working, you can move to the website design/implimentation